# Input type "time" without hours, mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, html, input

I would like to know if it's possible to force an input type time without hours, that only shows "00:00" in "mm:ss" format.
Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not talking about JS Date object. I'm talking about how to format the input type="time". If I add min="00:00" and max="59:59" attribute on it it doesn't work properly, so I need to know how to do that, if it's possible.
http://jsfiddle.net/g25jR/

Comment: I fear this may require a custom solution - unless you just add `step="1"` and have `hh:mm:ss` format - though building it yourself will mean the format you want, plus cross-browser compatibility, as even Firefox doesn't have 'proper' support for the time input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format in **`max`** and **`min`** is wrong

Try like this

```
<input type="time" step='1' min="00:00:00" max="20:00:00">
```

Comment: Oh god. That's my mistake... Now I solved my problem using step="1", works fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you might be able to do this with some smart JavaScript but you will find yourself in a tricky situation when it comes to cross browser compatibility, also if you need to support older browsers like IE8, they do not support HTML5 at all.

What is it exactly that you want to do?

For a good plain-JS (<3) fallback I would basically do something simple like this:

```
function getCurrentTime() {

   //Create a new date object.
   var oTime = new Date();

   //Get the minutes from the current date object.
   var minutes = oTime.getMinutes();

   //Get the seconds from the current date object.
   var seconds = oTime.getSeconds();

   //Optional: Add leading zero's
   if (minutes < 10)
       minutes = '0'+minutes;

   if (seconds < 10)
       seconds = '0'+seconds;

   //Return the current minutes and seconds
   return minutes+':'+seconds;

}
```

You could create a function that would put the result of the one above in an input field for instance, however this is current time if you seek something else, e.g. a time in the future, this is abit different to accomplish so I won't go there yet :)

Comment: Good solution for all browsers that doesn't support HTML5. I will try to implement it on my code. Thanks!!